# How can I find the nth derivative of the function $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2} \text{, if } x \neq 0 \text{ and } 0 \text{, if } x=0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

There is a function

> $f(x):=
> \begin{cases}
> e^{-1/x^2}, & \text{if $x \neq 0$} \\
> 0, & \text{if $x=0$}
> \end{cases} $.

That function's $n$-th derivative is $0$ : $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$.
How to derive that?

Comment: you mean that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$?

Comment: Yes, I made a typo. Thanks.

Comment: [These notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~mklipper/3100/F14/indepth-week14-end-f14.pdf) have it.

Comment: Your function is incorrectly stated... the function has no $n$ as a variable (i.e., it does not depend upon $n$), and then you use $n$ to refer to a *derivative*.  Please fix your question.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I changed the error n to x.